# AWK string comparison by alphabetical order

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk

The problem is simple.
I have an **AWK script** and I have two strings (names). If they have the same length, I need to pick the one which is "**sooner**" **in the alphabet** according to [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

first example:

```
 1st string = "aac", 2nd string = "aab"
```

result: `aab`

second example:

```
1st string = "Donald J Cat", 2nd string = "Donald J Bat"
```

result : `Donald J Bat`

Is there a simple way how to do it in AWK ?

Comment: Why not use `sort` for this instead of awk?

Comment: With bash: `[[ "aab" < "aac" ]] && echo "aab sorts before aac lexicographically"`

Comment: I have a pretty long AWK script hence I don't want to rewrite it to something else just becuse of this one thing.

Comment: What you describe is how string comparison works by default. I assume you tried something and didn't get the result you want so post a [mcve] demonstrating the actual problem you're trying to solve. Also you said `If they have the same length...` - what do you want to happen if they DON'T have the same length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
if ("aab" < "aac") {print "aab is sooner"}
```

Answer (score 0):

assume the compared fields are first and second, print the one that is shorter, or if equal length based on lexical order (aka dictionary order)

```
awk '...
     len1=length($1); len2=length($2);
     f = len1<len2 || (len1==len2 && $1<$2);
     print f?$1:$2; ...'
```

if you want case insensitive change to `tolower($1)<tolower($2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with two strings, you can use awk's behavior with string comparison and a ternary to assign the two strings to a single string in the order you describe:

```
$ echo "aac,aab
Donald J Cat,Donald J Bat
zoom batman,ahem Mr President
zzzzzz,a
aa,z" | awk -F, '{s=$1<$2 ? $1 "," $2 : $2 "," $1; print s}'
aab,aac
Donald J Bat,Donald J Cat
ahem Mr President,zoom batman
a,zzzzzz
aa,z
```

This will print the two words in asciibetical order; an `a` beats a full hand of `zzzz`'s

If you wanted to sort more than one string, and you have a recent `gawk` vs POSIX awk, you can use `PROCINFO` to traverse an array sorted by values:

```
echo "aac,aab,Donald J Cat,Donald J Bat
zoom batman,ahem Mr President,zzzzzz,a,aa,zz" | awk -F, '{s="";split("",a);
                                                    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i
                                                    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
                                                    for (e in a) s=s a[e] ","
                                                    print gensub(",$","","1",s)}'
Donald J Bat,Donald J Cat,aab,aac
a,aa,ahem Mr President,zoom batman,zz,zzzzzz
```

Note that in asciibetical sorting `'D'<'a'`. In gawk, it is easy to write a custom comparison function if needed.

Comment: but also `aa < z`, not sure if length needs to be considered first.

Comment: I guess it depends on the definition. The OP did not define the case of strings of different length. `aa < z` seems like the 'right' answer for a dictionary sort, but it is unclear what the OP is looking for in this case. If there is a requirement for length and ascii sorting -- so much more of a reason to write a custom PROCINFO sort function.